# how to remove devices from apple provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, device, provisioning-profile

I have a addhoc iOS application, this app has several associated devices in the Apple provisioning profile. Some of choose devices are not used any longer and I want to remove them. When I clicked the "disable" button I got this warning "disabling this device will invalidate all associated provisioning profiles. You can remove this device from your account at the start of your new membership year", What does the "remove this device from your account at the start of the year" mean. Is this not the way to remove devices? I'm confused...

Comment: Create new profiles without that devices.

Comment: Every year, we are doing renewal our apple account. After renewal it shows a message to remove device, that time you can delete those devices.

In middle only you can disable those device. So you profile will be not applicable for those devices.

Comment: Ok so my only option at this time is to disable the devices and the redownload the provisioning profile - build with that new profile. Is that correct?

Answer (score 6):

There is a limit of 100 devices you can register. Each device you register take 1 "place" of the 100 you have. 
You can have this space back only once a year - when you renew you account.
When you renew your account, you have again the choice to include devices.

But after you registered a device, you can't unregister it until the renew process. You can disable it, but it will still take 1 "place" from your 100 devices.

Edit: if you do disable the device, the provision profiles containing this device would be invalid, so just edit them and generate them again

Comment: I disable the ones no longer needed and then the provisioning profiles got invalid, I was able to edit one of them and download it, but there are still 3 provisioning profiles that are invalid that I cannot edit since that option is greyed out. Those 3 profiles are managed by xcode. How can I get them to be valid?

Comment: You can't edit them, xcode manage them for you. When you run your app on the device, xcode should suggest fixing those profile for you.

Comment: Hmmm, I have succesfully built the app and also installed it on my iPad (withouth Xcode complaining about anything), it does not work as it should though. Could what I done now affect the application in any way? I mean, if I can compile and install it it should work, right?

Answer (score 1):

It means that when your apple developer program renews, that time it will ask to reset the device list.